# Using parsnip to call multinomial_naive_bayes

Tags: r, nlp, naivebayes, tidymodels, parsnip

I want to use tidymodels to build a workflow for an NLP problem. I have a basic flow built in the traditional way using the `naivebayes` package, which basically feeds a document-term matrix (counts of terms occurring in each document) to the `multinomial_naive_bayes` function.

While there is a `parsnip` [interface for the naivebayes package](https://parsnip.tidymodels.org/reference/details_naive_Bayes_naivebayes.html) it only seems to work with the generic `naive_bayes` function. According to the [naivebayes documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/naivebayes/naivebayes.pdf) it seems to be the only format that can't be accessed through the generic function:

> Please note that the Multinomial Naive Bayes is not available through the naive_bayes function.

So... my 3 questions are:

1. Is there a way to access the `multinomial_naive_bayes` function using `parsnip`?
2. Is there a way to use the generic `naive_bayes` function with data in this format (counts of features)?
3. What's the best alternative? I see `parsnip` also supports `h2o` and `klaR` but I'm not familiar with those packages.

I'm expecting the answers to Qs 1 & 2 are "no", but worth checking. Advice on Q3 would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm expecting the answers to Qs 1 & 2 are "no", but worth checking.

Correct. We don't have engines for that/those. You could add an [issue to add them though](https://github.com/tidymodels/discrim/issues).

> Advice on Q3 would be welcome.

Check out the [textrecipes](https://textrecipes.tidymodels.org) package. It might get you to where you want to be in terms of processing the text and would seamlessly work with those engines that tidymodels supports at the moment. That package is excellent has many capabilities that would otherwise be a pain to use.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmations - I've created an issue. Thanks also for the `textrecipes` suggestion - I don't think it fixes my immediate issue but I'll bear it in mind for future reference